# iframe src attribute doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I encountered this problem after trying to make an HTML file that can change the URL, go to a home page, reload it, go to previous pages in history, etc. But after trying to use the src element to embed the google new tab, I didn't get anything. The content was just blank. I tried removing styles from CSS and importing them directly into the element, changing the order of the attributes, and even looked up the iframe element using w3schools.com. Nothing seems to work.

```css
#Top {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 613px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.Spacer {
  width: 15px;
  opacity: 0;
}

#URL {
  width: 350px;
}

#Dropdown {
  height: 23px;
}

iframe {
  width: 613px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="Top">
  <button id="back">
    &#60;
  </button><button class="Spacer">
  
  </button><button id="forward">
  &#62;
  </button><button class="Spacer">
  
  </button><button id="Reload">
  &#8635;
  </button><button class="Spacer">
  
  </button><button id="Off">
  O
  </button><button class="Spacer">
  
  </button><button id="Home">
  
  </button><button class="Spacer">
  
  </button><input id="URL" autoComplete="false"><button class="Spacer">
  
  </button><button id="Dropdown">
  ☰
  </button>
</div><iframe id="main" src="https://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
```

Can anyone tell me why this happens?

Comment: W3Schools has specified [`X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) in their response. The console in your browser's developer tools will usually include a message about it to help explain.

Comment: It is a sameorigin problem. In which framework or language you are working? same with "https://www.google.co.in/"